# How do I fix "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sqlalchemy'" when using flask_sqlalchemy?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, pip, pycharm, flask-sqlalchemy

I am trying to use flask_sqlalchemy, but when I run my script it throws up the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\files\main.py", line 2, in <module>
    from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
  File "C:\files\Python\Python310\site-packages\flask_sqlalchemy\__init__.py", line 13, in <module>
    import sqlalchemy
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sqlalchemy'
```

I have both flask_sqlalchemy and sqlalchemy installed and am having trouble figuring out why it is saying this. Also, PyCharm recognises both libraries as being installed and offers its usual predictive features when typing stuff to do with them.

Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: Are you sure it's installed in "C:\files\Python\Python310\site-packages\sqlalchemy"?

Comment: I've just installed it and it has helped, thankyou! What is the difference between having it installed there and PyCharm installing it in the virtual environment? Thanks for your help